# Investigating a property related to the biconnected property

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, connectedness

Let $(X, \tau) $ be a topological space and $A, B\subset X$ connected.

We know that $A\cap B\neq \emptyset$ implies $A\cup B$ is connected.

We also know that $A\cup B$ connected doesn't imply $A\cap B\neq \emptyset$

For an example $(\Bbb{R}, \tau_{\textrm{cofinite}})$ with $A=\Bbb{Q}$ and $B=\Bbb{R}\setminus \Bbb{Q}$

---

Now consider the following situation:

A topological space $(X, \tau)$ have the property $\text{SG}$ if $\forall A, B\subset X$ (with $A,B$ more than $1$ point) connected be such that $A\cup B$ connected implies $A\cap B\neq\emptyset$

The property $\text{SG}$  is vacuously satisfied by any totally disconnected space.

Is the classification of the $\text{SG}$ property already done?

If yes then list some interesting property of the space satisfying $\text{SG}$ property.

Comment: SG - the “Sourav Ghosh” property? Probably this rules out the usual nice spaces, I can see for instance that $\Bbb R^n$ is not SG if $n\ge2$. Not sure about $n=1$. This rules out any higher than 1-dimensional manifold too

Comment: Actually $\Bbb R$ ($n=1$) is clearly also not an SG space

Comment: Any space with $2$ or $3$ points is an SG space. More interestingly, any connected space with a so-called dispersion point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_point

Comment: Hi.  I have changed the title to a more informative one, easier to search for.  Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recall that a topological space is *biconnected*, if it is connected but is not the union of two disjoint connected subsets, which both have more than one point.

This is a standard notation, see for instance [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166864195000052) of M.E. Rudin. (In this paper, by definition, connected spaces have more than one point. So, this is true for biconnected spaces as well. But for our purpose it is better that spaces with at most one point are biconnected as well.)

In the following, $X$ is always a topological space.

The following lemma, which is certainly folklore, is crucial. For the easy proof see for instance [here](https://ir.cwi.nl/pub/13258), lemma 9 on p. 10 (T1 is not needed.)

**Lemma.**
Let $X$ be connected, $C$ a connected subset of $X$ and $T$  a component of $X \setminus C$.
Then $X \setminus T$ is connected.

This implies immediately connectness of $B^\prime$ in the following (the other properties are obvious):

**Corollary.**
Let $X$ be connected, $A, B$ disjoint connected subsets of $X$ and $a \in A$.
Define
$A^\prime := C_{X \setminus B}(a) =$ the component of $a$ in $X \setminus B$ and
$B^\prime := X \setminus A^\prime$.
Then
$A \subset A^\prime$,  $B \subset B^\prime$,
$A^\prime$ and $B^\prime$ are connected
and $X$ is the disjoint union of $A^\prime$ and $B^\prime$.

For the next theorem it is convenient to define:

$X$ is *strongly SG*, if for all connected subsets
$A, B$ of $X$, each with more than one point, it is
$A \cap B \neq \emptyset$.

So, in contrast to SG, here it is not assumed that
$A \cup B$ is connected.
It is easy to see (but will not be used here)
that a space is strongly SG, iff it is SG and has at most one component with more than one point.

**Theorem.**
The following are equivalent:

1. $X$ is biconnected.
2. $X$ is connected and strongly SG.
3. $X$ is connected and SG.

PROOF.
$1 \Rightarrow 2$:
Let $A, B$ be connected subsets, each with more than one point. Assume $A \cap B = \emptyset$.
Pick $a \in A$ and define $A^\prime, B^\prime$ as in the corollary, which implies a contradiction to biconnectness of $X$.  
$2 \Rightarrow 3$ is trivial. 
$3 \Rightarrow 1$ is straightforward, since $X$ is connected.

Remark.
The crucial step $1 \Rightarrow 2$ is also mentioned in M.E. Rudin's paper (see above).  But I couldn't find a proof of it. Therefore I included it here.

**Corollary.**
The following are equivalent:

1. $X$ is SG.
2. Each connected subset of $X$ is biconnected.
3. Each component of $X$ is biconnected.
4. Each component of $X$ is SG.

PROOF.
$1 \Rightarrow 2$:
Let $C$ be a connected subset of $X$. Trivially, $C$ is SG as well. Hence biconnected. 
$2 \Rightarrow 3$ is trivial. 
$3 \Rightarrow 1$:
Let $A, B$ be subsets of $X$ with more than one point each and $A, B, A \cup B$ be connected.
Hence, $A \cup B$ is contained in a component $C$ of $X$. Since $C$ is biconnected, it is SG. Hence, $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$.  
$1 \Leftrightarrow 4$ is straightfoward
(or, formally, $3 \Leftrightarrow 4$ follows immediately by the theorem).

**Notes.**

1. By 4. it might suffice to restrict investigations of SG spaces to connected SG spaces, hence to biconnected spaces.
2. As user14111 already commented, (connected) spaces with a dispersion point are examples of SG spaces. In M.E. Rudin's paper it is proved that under Martin's Axiom there exists a biconnected space in the plane without a dispersion point, which gives another example. Or see [here](https://www.emis.de/journals/HOA/IJMMS/22/2251.pdf) for a ZFC construction of a biconnected space without a dispersion point, which, however, is not regular.

Comment: ✅Excellent presentation.

Comment: This is a very clear and informative answer.  To put one of the main conclusions in words, the Theorem gives two equivalent characterizations of a biconnected space: (1) a connected space that cannot be partitioned into two connected subsets, each with at least two points; (2) a connected space which does not contain two disjoint connected subsets, each with at least two points.  (feel free to add this somewhere in the text to make it easier to reference maybe)

Comment: FYI, the "folklore" lemma is Theorem X in Knaster & Kuratowski (Fundamenta Mathematicae 2 (1921), 206-255).  That's the fundamental paper on connected sets that introduced the notion of biconnectedness.  And the same paper explicitly mentions the equivalence between 1. and 2. in the Theorem above, as a consequence of their Theorem XI.